# Two layers with same projection do not overlap

Tags: coordinate-system

I have a boundary layer for an area, the layer properties are:

```
top: 4431527.680136 m
bottom: 4431199.984995 m
left: 569103.516495 m
right: 569438.079758 m

Projected Coordinate System:    NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_15N
Projection: Transverse_Mercator
False_Easting:  500000.00000000
False_Northing: 0.00000000
Central_Meridian:   -93.00000000
Scale_Factor:   0.99960000
Latitude_Of_Origin: 0.00000000
Linear Unit:    Meter

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_North_American_1983
Datum:  D_North_American_1983
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree
```

Now, I have a new line shapefile (that I received from someone else) that is supposed to overlay on top of my layer but it did not. The new shapefile did not have any coordinate system. I defined it with the GCS North American 1983. I tried projecting it to NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_15N but it does not work. Here are the layer properties for the new layer. I am confused about the extent in dd.

```
top: 5194.424316 dd
bottom: 4802.068848 dd
left: 4754.654785 dd
right: 5162.077148 dd

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_North_American_1983
Datum:  D_North_American_1983
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree
```

Does anyone have any suggestion?

Comment: My bet is that even though a projection wasn't defined, the data you received was created/recorded in a different projection. Try and get in touch with them about possible projections it could be in, or run through some of the common projections for this region. Do you know the origin of the fiel?

Answer (score 0):

That other shapefile was created within some coordinate system. You have to know what that system was or try guessing.

If you want to try guessing, check the coordinates it list for one of its features, notice if it's using metess or degrees, and then compare those to common coordinate systems like some WGS 84 based one (EPSG 3857 or 4326).

If you don't know how to do any of that, drop me a line.

Comment: Yeah, I will need help on that. I think the shapefile is in decimal degrees.

Comment: OK, that probably means that shapefile is on a geographic coordinate system, meaning it is not projected onto a chosen plan just yet.  Can you give me some co-ordinates and the supposed location to see if it's using Northing from the Equator and Easting from Greenwich Meridian?

Comment: The area is in Knox county in Missouri state, USA. Few points when I hover over the shape file shows 4996.015, 5038.651 / 5011.626, 5004.215 / 4925.308, 4925.243 / 5104.831, 5150.681.

Comment: Probably Stateplane Missouri Central

Comment: Ok, that is not in decimal degrees.  Those are pretty small values… so essentially the datum (origin) of whatever that co-ordinate system is lies about 5000 meters south and east of Knox County. Which is specially strange as nation/state coordinate systems have the datum somewhere around the middle of the represented area.  My guess is, those values are given using some sort of 'on the fly' CRS transformation.  What software are you using? If you want to try NAD83 / Missouri Central choose the EPSG:26997.

Comment: As @klewis said, they could be NAD83 State Plane Missouri Central, BUT with a custom unit. The SPCS values should be 512k to 546k eastings (x) and 457k to 496k northings (y). So, maybe, if the values were divided by 100, rather than 1000? There's no possibility that they're in degrees or even some variation of degrees.